# Alternative way to get results faster without applying UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this udf which returns alert severity based on certain conditions.

```
def alert(name, X_Request, X_Actual):
    if "Impact" in name:
        return "Highest"

    fs = ['FS_00','FS_01','FS_02','FS_03']
    if name in fs:
      if X_Actual < -3:
          return "High"
      elif X_Actual <= -2 and X_Actual >= -3 :
          return "Medium"
      elif X_Actual > -3 and X_Actual <= -0.5:
          return "Low"
    return None

alert_type = udf(alert, StringType())


df.withColumn("alert_level", alert_type(df["name"],df["x_request"],df["x_actual"]))
```

Can this be done without applying UDF, as UDF slows down the performance?

Comment: looks like a `when().otherwise()` (SQL's case when equivalent) should work

Comment: shouldn't the "Low" condition be > -2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `when().otherwise()` like the following should work.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
fs = ['FS_00','FS_01','FS_02','FS_03']

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('alert_level',
               func.when(func.upper(func.col('name')).like('%IMPACT%'), func.lit('Highest')).
               when(func.col('name').isin(fs), 
                    func.when(func.col('x_actual') < -3, func.lit('High')).
                    when(func.col('x_actual').between(-3, -2), func.lit('Medium')).
                    when(func.col('x_actual').between(-2, -0.5), func.lit('Low'))
                    )
               )
```

Note - [`.between()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.between.html#pyspark-sql-column-between) includes the bounds provided to it (it's a `>=` & `<=`). But in this case it is safe due to the `when()` order of execution (anything `=2` will already be considered in `"Medium"`). Any other value that does not match the conditions will result in a `null` as no `otherwise()` condition was provided.