# Pyspark dataframe handling

Tags: pyspark

Sorry, I need your help to make this manipulation in pyspark.

I have this dataframe

```
data = [['tom', True,False], ['nick', True,False], ['juli', False,True]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age','gender'])
```

and I want to have

```
data = [['tom', True,False,1], ['nick', True,False,1], ['juli', False,True,2]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'cond1','cond2',"stat"])
```

I mean if cond1 ==True, stat = 1 and if cond2 ==True, stat = 2

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: what if both are true or both are false in the same record?

Comment: It is impossible in my use case but if the both are false, stat = ""

Comment: this is a simple case when operation -- see how to use `when().otherwise()`. [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73302140/8279585)